# Cloning a bitbucket git repo in more than one location fails

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a git repo hosted with bitbucket and i have a clone on my home directory and i was thinking of cloning another inside `/var/www` directory.When i try cloning another copy into my `www` folder i get this error

```
Cloning into 'php'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

There is nothing wrong with my public key since i can push changes to bitbucket from the cloned repo i have on the home folder and i can see the latest commits i have made on the bitbucket website.

Is there a known explanation for this behavior?.

Comment: Are you trying to clone as a different user (www-data or root)? These users don't use the private key of your own user account.

Comment: I am doing sudo git clone https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/php.git so its root.

Comment: Then that's probably the issue. Note that you do not have to re-clone the entire repository, you can simply copy it over to the new location and set then change the owner with `chown`.

Comment: I had earlier tried to make www writable by sudo chmod -R a+rwX /var/www so i just copied the php repo i had cloned into the home directory,opied it into var/www and i can now commit and push from the repo at /var/www.

Comment: Making the complete directory /var/www world writable is not the best idea either …

Comment: I have reverted the permissions for /var/www.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you need to clone the repository into the /var/www. I think that the best solution is to create a symbolic link of the repository into the /var/www. That way you don't need to synchronize two repositories.

But if want to create another repository into the /var/www directory, you need to give permission to your user to write in the directory or create a new publickey for your root user and copy it to the bitbucket.